# mysqldump restore issues

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to create a backup of my db.
i have separated the schema and the data in two different sql files from mysql dump.
when i try to restore the schema works fine, but when i execute the data.sql file i get too many errors.

[sql error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxhun.jpg)

please check the link for the error

Comment: you have to put the data in the right order (according to constraints) or - just for a test - create constraints after data filling

Comment: how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be that you are trying to insert data into some columns which reference to another column which is not populated yet thereby the query is failing on integrity checks. I suggest you create one sql dump for both the schema and data and run it once. That may save you this headache.

Comment: I have used this command for getting only the data:
mysqldump --no-create-info --skip-triggers -h%server% -u%user% -p dbname% > "%backupdestination%\%date:/=%_Data.sql"

is there a work around? i need to have the schema and data seperate. could it be because of the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, the stored procedure may also give you issues in some instances. How many tables are you exporting from?

Comment: around 30-40 tables.
I fixed the issue by taking 3 dumps.
1.Schema
2. Only triggers and stored procedures 
3. Just the Data. 

if i restore in the same order it seems to work fine :)